# Bootstrap mail form - received from variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, email, email-headers, formmail

Using a Bootstrap mail form. Form delivers mail, except in the from variable it displays the server name instead of the sender's email address.

Could someone explain how I get the $name variable to display as "from" OR at the very least, display the name of the domain the email was sent from rather then the server name?

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $business = $_POST['business'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From website of xxxxxx'; 
        $to = 'user@somedomainname.com'; 
        $subject = 'New Message ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Business Name: $business\n  Phone: $phone\nMessage: $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

         // Check if business has been entered
        if (!$_POST['business']) {
            $errBusiness = 'Please enter your business or organization name';
        }

         // Check if phone has been entered
        if (!$_POST['phone']) {
            $errPhone = 'Please enter your phone number';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch.</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: The `from` field is to be an email address, like noreply@yourdomain. Try if that already does the trick.

Comment: I tried that prior to posting and it does not work Jan. Email (from:) is still showing the server name where the site is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may reside in your call to the `mail` function.

[As the docs say](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php),

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

and, more interestingly,

> ## additional_headers (optional)
>
> String to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.
>
> Note:
>
> additional_headers does not have mail header injection protection. Therefore, users must make sure specified headers are safe and contains headers only. i.e. Never start mail body by putting multiple newlines.
>
> Note:
>
> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.
>
> Note:
>
> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

Comment: I get the optional additional headers, however I am not sure I understand "mail function." as the PHP I posted is all there is besides a Bootstrap validation script. Here's what I get when the form is posted: domainname@servername.com

Comment: `additional headers` is inserted as raw in the header parts. So `$from` should be something like `From: noreply@yourdomain.tld`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to was to add a line to the php.ini file and drop in root directory of server. Did not have to add $headers to existing script of mod the from: line.

Some would prefer the from: line to display the actual sender's address, but I've found this creates havoc with spam filters as each form submitted is from a different user. I am sure there is a way to correct this, just now 100% sure how to do so,

```
sendmail_path="/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@somedomainname.com"
```

Comment: That is completly covered in my answer. Did you even read the cited part of the documentation?